# Generate dynamic table based upon form's multiple select box

Tags: php, dynamic, html-table

I have been trying so hard to figure this out and although close, I just can't figure something out. My code is as follows...

```
 <?php
include('functions.php');
connect();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fieldName = $_POST['fieldName'];
    foreach($fieldName AS $key=>$values){
        $fieldList .= $values;

    }
    $fieldList = implode(',', $fieldName); //comma separated list
    echo $rowList;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ".$fieldList." FROM members");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
        echo "<th>";
        echo $col;
        echo "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['city']."</td><td>".$row['firstName']."</td><td>".$row['cellPhone']."</td></tr>";//***HOPING TO GENERATE THIS DYNAMICALLY WITH VARIABLES...MAYBE ANOTHER FOREACH???
    }
    echo "</table>";

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<select name="fieldName[]" multiple="yes" id="fieldName">
    <option value="">Select all that apply</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
    <option value="lastName">Last Name</option>
    <option value="firstName">First Name</option>
    <option value="state">State</option>
    <option value="cellPhone">Cell Phone</option>
</select>           
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am so close but I do not understand how to create the "echo statement" that resides between my while loop above.  My guess is that I will do something similar to ...`$fieldList .= $values;`  where the statement will grow as needed depending on how many items the user selects in my dropdown box.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.  Please find below the code I used to generate the dynamic table listing I was seeking...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($fieldName as $value){
        echo "<td>".$row[$value]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I hope this can help someone who is trying to create a simple reporting facility.